# Polymorhism and the class Object

Tags: java, polymorphism

We know that each class extends from Object which means that we can use all Object's methods
in any class. My problem is the following:

```
   interface B{

       }

       public class A implements B{
          public static void main(String[] args){

             B i = new A();
             i.display();//we can't do this : because the interface B doesn't define such a method

             System.out.println(i.toString());// we can do this although the interface doesn't extend from Object                           

          }
          public void display(){         

          }

      }
```

so I think the problem is clear , why I could invoke the toString method although the interface B can't extend from Object?

Comment: `A` extends from `Object`.

Comment: No, it sort of does. Every `Object` in Java has a `toString`. An _instance of_ `B` is an `Object`.

Comment: Because, as you're saying in the question: We know that each class extends from Object which means that we can use all Object's methods in any class

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth What `A` extends from is not relevant to a variable of type `B`. This is a valid question about the type system.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: That's a fair point; I hadn't noticed that the object was being accessed through a `B` reference.

Answer (score 5):

This is spelled out in the [JLS §9.2. Interface Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2):

> - If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a `public` `abstract` member method `m` with signature `s`, return type `r`, and `throws` clause `t` corresponding to each `public` instance method `m` with signature `s`, return type `r`, and `throws` clause `t` **declared in `Object`**, unless an `abstract` method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible `throws` clause is explicitly declared by the interface.

This ensures that it is possible to call `Object` methods via any interface.

Comment: So theoretically there's *sort of* like an `interface Object` which all upper-most interfaces (those with no super class) extend?